# Openshift github status result

Tags: openshift

I've managed to get `openshift` to download my `github` commits and fire on a `webhook` without issue. What I'd love to be able to do though is make use of the [Github Status](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) API to be able to mark builds as good or bad.

Has anyone had any success in doing this? If so how do you do it? I was thinking of doing it via the `postBuild` hook in `openshift` however I don't think I have access to the SHA nor would I be albe to post on failure.

Answer (score 1):

The `OPENSHIFT_BUILD_COMMIT` environment variable, along with a few others, will be set in the image and provide details about the remote repo used.

- https://docs.openshift.org/3.9/dev_guide/builds/build_output.html#output-image-environment-variables

You should be able to see those from the hook you run in the image as part of the `postCommit` hook.

Comment: This would get the commit info, but I'm concerned that the postBuild command still couldn't alert on failed builds though. I think I may need to bake the information into a s2i script (Which I was really really hoping not to do!)

Comment: Yeah, this would only work for successfil build, or if the build failed because of separate tests run during the ``postCommit``. Not sure if there is a way of having hook called on failure to build image in first place.